# does django-tables2 work with django1.8 and bootstrap3?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-tables2

With Django 1.8, Python 3.4, and Bootstrap 3, the table renders but it is missing the grid/css.(see image below).

I've installed django-tables2  per [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) I also ran collecstatic(localhost) It also appears in my virtualenv django1834/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated

#settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

#views.py

```
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from cdpapp.tables import WorkOrderTable
...

def list_all_workorders(request):
table = WorkOrderTable(WorkOrder.objects.all())
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request, 'cdpapp/workorder_all_list.html', {'table': table})
```

#tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.utils import A  # alias for Accessor
from cdpapp.models import WorkOrder

class WorkOrderTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = ("call_date", "ordernum", "building", "unit", "request_by", 'problem_desc')
    attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

#template

```
{% extends "cdpapp/base_no_side_panel.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}All Work Orders{% endblock %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
</head>

{% block content %}
{% render_table table %}
{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is how you defined `attrs`. `attrs` should be an element of the `Meta` class in the `Table` class. You need to indent `attrs` one more level.

```py
class WorkOrderTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = ("call_date", "ordernum", "building", "unit", 
                "request_by", 'problem_desc')
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

Also, will you please clarify your question?

You say it is missing the 'grid/css'. Does this mean you want your table to show borders?

While running your test server are you able to retrieve the `screen.css` file via the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css. If the css file doesn't load then you may have some settings set up wrong.